# highlight the entire focus row in ListView

Tags: android, listview

How could I highlight the entire row ,instead of only the space occupied with characters, in the listview when the row get focused.

For example below, I want the whole line to be highlighted, instead of just "Hello Stackoverflow".

```
|hello Stackoverflow.                                                    |END
```

Comment: could you show your xml please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your item has `layout_width` set to `fill_parent` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Turns out should set `ListView` itself to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Answer (score 2):

in yor list in background property you add 
@drawable/listItemDrawables

in drawable folder named as listItemDrawables.xml you put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/onFocusImage" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/imageWithNoFocus" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

and add two images in drawable folder
onFocusImage.png
and 
imageWithNoFocus

now when you select something from the list you will got a felling like everything is selected